# Separate scheme for Performance Test in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, jenkins, xcode-ui-testing

Is there any advantage of creating separate `Performance Test scheme` in Xcode (similar to schemes like `Unit Test` and `UI Test`) except for the fact that testing code is more segregated? Is it worth keeping 3 testing schemes for a single Xcode project?

What I meant to say is that even if I write all my performance test cases in `self.measure{ }` block in the same Unit test bundle (scheme), will it make any difference once the project grows and is subjected to continuous integration in Jenkins?

What is the industrial standard of implementing `Performance testing in Xcode`? Do everyone keep performance testing in the same Unit test bundle? Why and Why not?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, note that **scheme** and **target** are not the same thing:

> A [target](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html) specifies a product to build and contains the instructions for building the product from a set of files in a project or workspace.

As you said, when it comes to tests, a target is used to group a set of tests, what is called a test bundle. Having several tests targets lets you easily run only a specific subset of all your test cases. Thus, is specially useful to separate performance tests in a specific test target, because these tests usually take more time to run. So it's useful to be able to only run the faster unit tests.

> A [scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Schemes.html) defines a collection of targets to build, **a configuration to use when building**, and a collection of tests to execute.

(Emphasis is mine) Here is the trick, and the answer to your question: For performance tests, having a dedicated scheme to run them is specially important, because this lets you build the app with a different build configuration. And you want to do that, because you want to compile your app in release mode, so your **performance tests run against an optimized build**.
[Scheme with app built in specific build config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeoK9.png)

To be precise, for performance tests, you need to add a new build configuration that is just like Release, but with the "Enable Testability" build flag on.
This "Enable Testability" is needed for the tests to link to your app. So on your project you will have 3 build configurations: Release, Debug and PerformanceTests.

[3 build configurations image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6dJP.png)

[Enable Testability image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AywSO.png)

On the other hand, with unit tests, you want to compile the app in debug mode, so you can set breakpoints to debug a failing test for example.

Also note that since you are adding custom configuration in the schemes, it's a good idea to make them shared, so everybody contributing to your project have the same.

You can see all this in action in [SwiftGraph project](https://github.com/davecom/SwiftGraph). More specifically this was implemented in [this commit](https://github.com/davecom/SwiftGraph/commit/e3ba814c2538d748877b19881dc7da08bd9ab545)